# Always display tic marks in boxplot

Tags: r, plot

When I separate a boxplot using a formula, the tics on the x-axis are labeled:

```
frame <- data.frame(
    foo = c(1:5),
    bar = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 1)
)
boxplot(formula = foo ~ bar, data = frame)
```

[image]

However, if there is nothing for the formula to separate no tics or labels appear:

```
frame <- data.frame(
    foo = c(1:5),
    bar = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
)
boxplot(formula = foo ~ bar, data = frame)
```

[image]

How do I force both the tics and label?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add the line to your code

```
axis(side = 1, at = unique(frame$bar))
```

such that
[image]
[image]